# Access PA-35 Wifi Actuator Control Box from outside IP

Tags: networking, router, wan

I purchased an actuator that can be controlled by an iOS app as long as you are connected to the network this control box creates. I want to be able to set up a DNS and access the controls where ever I am. Called their support, no one knows anything on their end, but they heard of people successfuly doing this. The router that's being used in the house is the Hitron CGN3ROG.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should note that doing this will expose the actuator over the Internet. As most such devices have no or very little security, this could be a massive problem to you.

Having said that, it is pretty easy. Firstly you need to set up a path from the Internet to the device. This is done by configuring "forwarding" on the router. You choose an externally facing IP port and the IP address and port of the device and link them together. This allows traffic to flow from the Internet direct to your device.

Then you need to know the external IP address of your broadband. This may change from time to time so you may need a way to get notified when it does. There are a number of services that will allow this to happen though your router needs to support them or you need another machine on your local network that does.

Now you can access your device from the Internet. If your external IP address is fixed, you don't need DNS. Otherwise, you need the "Dynamic DNS" service mentioned above.

UPDATE: To get a port forwarded on your router, you can refer to the helpful guides at [portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/HitronTechnologies/CGN3ROG/defaultguide.htm). It gives you a full walk-through.

Basically, you need to go into the Basic Settings and Port Forwarding page of the routers web site. Choose a name (doesn't matter what - something memorable), choose TCP for the Protocol, choose a public port range, e.g. 8000:8000, this is the port you will use when accessing from the outside world. Choose a private port range, this is the port that is active on the device. Finally put in 10.0.0.1 as the IP address. Now, as long as you know your external IP address - if you don't, you can find it by Googling "whatsmyip" - you should be able to access the device. Don't forget though that everyone else can access it too unless you have some other security on it.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the forwarding part. So the actuator control box has the IP 10.0.0.1 and I can only connect to the IP when my iPhone or mac is connected to the Wifi signal the control box gives off. How would I link this IP with my Hitron CGN3ROG router?